# Postgres add column category to view base on sum of specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I have the *animaltable* table:

| id | dog_amount | cat_amount | bird_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

and i wonna create view like this:

| id | animal | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dogs | 8 |
| 2 | cats | 9 |
| 3 | birds | 14 |

How can I achieve that? How to add the extra column "animal" to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION ALL` the different animals, in a *derived table* (i.e. the subquery.) `GROUP BY` its result.

```
create view animalview as

select animal, SUM(total)
from
(
    select 'dogs' animal, dog_amount   as total   from animaltable
    UNION ALL 
    select 'cats' animal, cat_amount   as total   from animaltable
    UNION ALL
    select 'birds' animal, bird_amount as total   from animaltable
) dt
group by animal
```

Comment: how add this to view to fit posrgress grammar?

Comment: Sorry for a lack of information at begin. I wanna use this select in subquery.

Comment: Go ahead, use it in a subquery. Shouldn't be a problem. Anyhow, this answers the question, and is expected to be "accepted". If you still have problems, ask another question. (You can even reference this question.)

Comment: I asked another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571981/postgres-view-field-from-subquery if you want to look at it, I would be grateful

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get the desired result, first I get total amount of each animal in a subquery (one row) and then use `LATERAL JOIN` with a "constant table" (using `VALUES`):

```
CREATE VIEW animals_view AS

SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT SUM(dog_amount) AS dogs, SUM(cat_amount) AS cats, SUM(bird_amount) AS birds
      FROM animaltable) AS t
JOIN LATERAL (VALUES (1, 'dogs', t.dogs), (2, 'cats', t.cats), (3, 'birds', t.birds)) AS s(id, animal, total) ON TRUE;
```

Comment: Upvoted! Just a comment, it's not the JOIN which is LATERAL. The LATERAL keyword belongs to its following derived table. I.e. it's a _lateral derived table_.