# Postgres view. Field from subquery with union all

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

Referring to this question:
[Postgres add column category to view base on sum of specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570588/postgres-add-column-category-to-view-base-on-sum-of-specific-column/69570651?noredirect=1#comment122969189_69570651)

How add total and animal form subquery to this view:

```
CREATE VIEW animal_report 
AS
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
        -- several columns form animal_location table --
        /subquery/.animal AS animal_category
        /subquery/.total AS total
    FROM
        animal_location
    LEFT JOIN 
        animal_table ON animal_location.id = animal_table.id
    GROUP BY
        animal_category
```

the subquery i wanna use:

```
select animal, SUM(total)
from
(
    select 'dogs' animal, dog_amount   as total   from animaltable
    UNION ALL 
    select 'cats' animal, cat_amount   as total   from animaltable
    UNION ALL
    select 'birds' animal, bird_amount as total   from animaltable
) dt
group by animal
```

Comment: You should shared tables structure (I saw animal_table structure in the other question, but not animal_location structure), sample data and the desired result.

Comment: animal_location structure isn't important here. What i wanna achieve is how use subquery where "union all" appear. Extra table animal_location make me problem with syntax, how to hold that when i wanna use 2 tables?

Comment: Ok, I don't understand what is the result you want. Think of the subquery as a table, write the subquery between parenthesis with an alias `(subquery) AS sq` and use it as it were a table.